# What is CPU_SUBTYPE for iphone5s 64 bit ?

Tags: iphone, 64-bit

I want to know what is the CPU_SUB_TYPE of the iphone 5S 64 bit.

For other architectures I am able to look in the machine.h file of the macho and get the lot of architecture. But I am implementing security project specific to iphone 5s 64 Bit architecture and unable to get exact details of it. Any link or source of information with answer will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

It is CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM_ALL  with little endian architecture. A little investigation on the machine.h file and trying out it on the executable of the iphone 5s 64bit binary led to this conclusion.